# TFS build server issues with Wix - Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.Interview.ProjectDir)'

Tags: wix, tfsbuild

I'm trying to set up a build server for our project so that the builds can be automated.

I can build locally and I have just checked in the build, yet I keep getting this error

C:\Builds\1\Deployment\Sources\Services\Deployment\Interview.wxs(19): error CNDL0150: Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.Interview.ProjectDir)'.

Locally it works, so the reference is there, but on TFS it seems not to be there.

I've just realized that I was too hasty

There is this warning as well

C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\wix2010.targets (971): The referenced project '..\Interview\Interview.csproj' does not exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: I removed all references to the interview project and it built fine, so.. 
not sure how to proceed now, re-add them?

Comment: So, I added a test console project and that built fine.
I then added a web application project and that built fine as well.
The question is why are the existing projects not building?
this is extremely frustrating

Comment: Sounds like WiX is not installed on a server when TFS is running. Or not the version your project expects.

Comment: This is question is too old, but in case somewhere else, but in my case was that for some reason the reference on the project file it was added with too many /../../.. ,and then it would add the folder tree.. and that tree does not exists on azure. So I just edited the project file and fixed the reference by hand.